# Prove that $x\log x$ is midpoint convex.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

> Prove that negative entropy function $f(x)=x\log x$ is midpoint convex on $(0,+\infty)$.

**Attempt**. Let $0<x<y$, so:
$$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\leq \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$
is equivalent to:
$$\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^{\frac{x+y}{2}}\leq x^{\frac{x}{2}} y^{\frac{y}{2}},$$ 
being equivalent to:
$$\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^{x+y}\leq x^x y^y.$$
The last inequality is equivalent to:
$$(x+y)^{x+y}\leq (2x)^x (2y)^y.$$
It would be enough to prove $(x+y)^{x}\leq (2x)^x,~(x+y)^{y}\leq (2y)^y$, but the first inequality doesn't seem to hold, though.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $f$ is convex? In such case, midpoint convexity is just a special case of convexity (and is in fact equivalent to convexity for a continuous function on an interval). As for the convexity of $f$, it easily follows from $f''(x) = 1/x > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying Jensen's inequality to $f$ is an easy way. Otherwise, you can apply GM-HM inequality to obtain
$$
x^{\frac{x}{x+y}}y^{\frac{y}{x+y}}\ge \frac{1}{\frac{x}{x+y}\frac1{x}+\frac{y}{x+y}\frac1{y}}=\frac{x+y}2.
$$

Comment: GM-HM inequaility is $\sqrt[n]{a_1\ldots a_n}\geq \frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_n}}$. In our case $n=2$ and what are $a_1$ and $a_2$? I mean, how do you get the LHS if the inequality?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout It is a [weighted version](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality#Weighted_Form) of AM-GM-HM inequality. It can also be viewed as [power means inequaltiy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Proof_of_power_means_inequality) corresponding to $(p,q) = (0,-1)$.